# Turn single pixel on/off or change color in Java

Tags: java, java-2d

How should I turn a each pixel on or off and change its color :-/

Comment: How does a pixel look like that has been switched off?

Comment: @Andreas_D: it's kind-off a bright mauve.

Comment: @OP. I won't downvote your question since you are new, but the question is incredible vague. Do you want to turn it off (whatever that is) in an image, in a graphics object, or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you use [BufferedImage](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html), there's a method called setRGB which should do what you want.

Answer (score 4):

If you're doing normal painting with a [`Graphics`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) (or [`Graphics2D`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html)) object (a.k.a using AWT/Swing), then [drawing a single-pixel line](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawLine%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) is the normal way:

```
int x = 100;
int y = 200;
g.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
```

Comment: Unchecked, but shouldn't the 3rd/4th args be `x+1, y+1`?

Comment: @Andrew: I've not tested it this time, but if I'm not mistaken, this should draw a single pixel. Let me test that. (Edit: verified)

Comment: Thanks for verifying.  That's sure 'gold service' forum contribution.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

<s>There are no methods for drawing pixels, to my knowledge, in java. What you do, is do use fillRect or drawLine (on a BufferedImage), with with and height equal to 1.
Use setRGB beforehand to set the color.</s>

However, if you are using this to create a single image, (like a fractal picture generator or similar), then there are much more efficient methods:

```
int pixels[] = new int[width * height];

//Draw pixels here, by using something like this:
pixels[y*width + x] = (alpha<<24) | (rgb[0]<<16) | (rgb[1]<<8) | rgb[2]

//Convert to an image like so:
MemoryImageSource source = new MemoryImageSource(width,height,pixels,0,width);
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(source);
```

Comment: "There are no methods for drawing pixels.." See [BufferedImage.setRGB(x,y,rgb)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#setRGB%28int,%20int,%20int%29).